# Why does LaTeX throw an error for this equation?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I am having a tough time reproducing the following equation in LaTeX:

> C =  2/(ω^2 N^(2 )µπa)

This is the code I have:

```
C = \frac{2}{\omega^2N^2\mu\pia}
```

However, this throws an error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Give a space between `\pi` and `a` like `\pi a`

Comment: You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Answer (score 6):

The correct solution is to seperate the `\pia` into `\pi a`. A slightly more in-depth explanation can be read below.

---

When you write

```
  C = \frac{2}{\omega^2N^2\mu\pia}
```

`TeX` sees only tokens. The character `^`, which initiates an "assignment" to use a superscript for the next token, takes a single token only. `\omega^2N^2` then produces the optical result of `{omega}superscript{2}<math kern/space*>{N}superscript{2}`.

A common way to include multiple tokens is to use the construction with braces. This allows you to typeset multiple tokens in superscript mode, e.g. `\omega^{2N+5}`. You already did this automatically with the `\frac` command, which takes two tokens. You can experiment with this by using for instance the command `\frac12` (not recommended, just for the purpose of showing the mechanism). This will typeset exactly the  same as `\frac{1}{2}` (which is probably the notation you're used to), and for the same reason `\omega^2` and `N^2` will work, *also* in the context of `\omega^2N^2`, since `TeX` goes back into regular math mode after having scanned the number `2` after `\omega`, and so `N^2` is typeset correctly as a regular `N` and consequently a superscript `2`.

The same cannot be said about `\pia`. The issue here is that `TeX` cannot know that you wish to typeset the character corresponding to "assignment" `\pi`, to consequently typeset the character `a`. Furthermore, `\pia` has no corresponding character or assignment to it, unless you `\def` it as such:

```
\def\pia{\ifmmode\pi a\fi}
```

...but that may be somewhat superfluous and won't contribute to prettier code or an easier workflow.

As Harish Kumar pointed out, a space between the two does the job.

---

* = This is almost the same as the textual space.

** = I used the term "assignment" rather loosely here.

Comment: Why not showing first the *correct* solution, which is typing `\pi a`?