# Undefined control sequence error for equation

Tags: equations

I am trying to reproduce the following equation in LaTeX:

> nopt(d, B) = argminn {Pt - LMI (d, n, ω + 0.5B) >= Pth }

and the syntax I have used is the following:

```
$n_{opt}\left(d, B\right) = argmin_n\lbraceP_t - L_{Mi}\left(d, n, \omega + 0.5B\right) \geq P_{th}\rbrace$
```

This does not compile and I get the

> `!Undefined Control Sequence Error.`

Any suggestions on what I am missing here?

Comment: Insert a space between `\lbrace` and `P`. (The error message you report receiving should indicate which control sequence -- here, `\lbraceP` -- is undefined.

Comment: It's the same mistake you did here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/224538/27635

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to fixing the erroneous input that's causing LaTeX to report an undefined control sequence error, viz., the lack of a space in `\lbraceP` -- you should (a) set up `argmin` as a math operator and (b) render "opt" in upright-roman rather than in math-italic mode. Incidentally, the `\left` and `\right` directives don't resize the respective parentheses since the material they enclose isn't large; all they do is to insert unnecessary whitespace and contribute to a "loose" look of the equation. In short, don't use `\left` and `\right` here.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for \DeclareMathOperator macro
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\newcommand{\opt}{\mathrm{opt}}

\begin{document}
\[
n_{\opt}(d, B) = \argmin_n\bigl\lbrace P_t - L_{Mi}(d, n, \omega + 0.5B) \geq P_{th}\bigr\rbrace
\]
\end{document}
```